# Rollup and material-components-web - issue transforming a node module

Tags: es6-modules, rollup, rollupjs

I am attempting to make a build file for the browser using rollup.js and Google's library material-components-web. I seem to be hitting a issue with material-components-web's drawer component:

```
$ rollup --config

data/www/assets/scripts/app.js â data/www/assets/scripts/bundle.js...
[!] Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/focus-trap/index.js
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
node_modules/@material/drawer/util.js (23:9)
21:  * THE SOFTWARE.
22:  */
23: import { default as createFocusTrap } from 'focus-trap';
             ^
24: export function createFocusTrapInstance(surfaceEl, focusTrapFactory) {
25:     if (focusTrapFactory === void 0) { focusTrapFactory = createFocusTrap; }
Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules/focus-trap/index.js
    at error (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:5365:30)
    at Module.error (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9708:9)
    at handleMissingExport (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:9625:21)
    at Module.traceVariable (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:10018:17)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:8685:39)
    at FunctionScope.findVariable (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:3056:38)
    at ChildScope.findVariable (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:3056:38)
    at BlockScope.findVariable (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:3056:38)
    at Identifier$1.bind (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:4394:40)
    at AssignmentExpression.bind (/home/one/.nvm/versions/node/v12.7.0/lib/node_modules/rollup/dist/rollup.js:3143:23)
```

Here is my rollup config:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'data/www/assets/scripts/app.js',
  output: {
    file: 'data/www/assets/scripts/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [resolve()]
};
```

Am I doing anything wrong on my side?